# getting Error implementing Pagefactory and explicit wait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Pagefactory and I want to implement Explicit wait in some methods in a page. here is overall structure of my code:

```
public class HomePage{ 

private String username;
private String password;
...

@FindBy(id= "username")
public static WebElement LoginUserName;
...

public LoginPage(RemoteWebDriver driver, ExtentTest test, Properties config) {
     this.driver = driver;
     this.test = test;
     this.config = config;
     PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}

public void enterUserName(String userName) throws Exception {
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(LoginUserName));
     if (LoginUserName.isDisplayed()) {
            LoginUserName.sendKeys(userName);
     } else {
            test.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Element Not found");
            throw new Exception("Element not found" + LoginUserName.toString());
     }
}
...
```

the code above works fine, but if I define          `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);`
outside of the `enterUserName` I get an error. I want to define the `WebDriverWait wait`  outside because I want to use it in other methods too. 
so, how can I define `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);` outside of `enterUserName` without getting error?

the error doesn't show a useful info (`Caught exception;>>>>>:null`)

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think moving the wait object initialization to the class constructor should solve this null pointer issue.

```
 public class HomePage{ 

private String username;
private String password;
private WebDriverWait wait;
...

@FindBy(id= "username")
public static WebElement LoginUserName;
...

public LoginPage(RemoteWebDriver driver, ExtentTest test, Properties config) {
     this.driver = driver;
     this.test = test;
     this.config = config;
     PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
     this.wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 10);
}

public void enterUserName(String userName) throws Exception {

     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(LoginUserName));
     if (LoginUserName.isDisplayed()) {
            LoginUserName.sendKeys(userName);
     } else {
            test.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Element Not found");
            throw new Exception("Element not found" + LoginUserName.toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error? How are you creating the page objects?

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct? 
As per your code:
Class Name: HomePage

```
public class HomePage{
```

Constructor: LoginPage

```
public LoginPage(RemoteWebDriver driver, ExtentTest test, Properties config) {
```

I would suggest keeping all the utility methods in a separate file will be good if you are creating a framework.

```
    /**
 * Explicit Wait for Element To Be Clickable.
 * @param driver
 * @param seconds
 * @param element
 */
public static void explicitWaitElementToBeClickable(WebDriver driver, int seconds, WebElement element) {
    try {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then use it something like:

```
WaitUtility.explicitWaitElementToBeClickable(driver, 10, loginUserName);
```

Comment: I have a utility method and it's a good suggestion. I'll do that later. but what's wrong with the available code?